# Evaluate $\det[[\lfloor\frac{aj-(a+1)k}n\rfloor]_q]_{1\le j,k\le n}$ and $\det[[\lceil\frac{(a+1)j-ak}n\rceil]_q]_{1\le j,k\le n}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, determinants, q-analogs, quadratic-residues

The $q$-analogue of an integer $m$ is defined by
$[m]_q=(1-q^m)/(1-q)$. Note that $\lim_{q\to1}[m]_q=m$.

I have formulated the following conjecture on determinants involving the floor function and the ceiling function.

**Conjecture.** Let $a$ be any integer, and let $n$ be a positive odd integer. Then
$$\det\left[\left[\left\lfloor\frac{aj-(a+1)k}n\right\rfloor\right]_q\right]_{1\le j,k\le n}=-\left(\frac{a(a+1)}n\right)q^{(1-3n)/2}\tag{1}$$
and
$$\det\left[\left[\left\lceil\frac{(a+1)j-ak}n\right\rceil\right]_q\right]_{1\le j,k\le n}=\left(\frac{a(a+1)}n\right)q^{(n-1)/2},\tag{2}$$
where $(\frac{\cdot}n)$ is the Jacobi symbol.

*Remark.* It is easy to see that the two determinants in $(1)$ and $(2)$ vanish when $n>2$ is even.
The conjectural identity $(1)$ appeared in my preprint [arXiv:2108.07723](http://arxiv.org/abs/2108.07723). Besides the two general patterns $(1)$ and $(2)$, I have also observed some special identities similar to $(1)$ and $(2)$, which have been confirmed by my graduate student Chen-Kai Ren.

**QUESTION.** Is the conjecture true? How to prove $(1)$ and $(2)$ for any integer $a$ and positive odd integer $n$?